# Run Docker Entrypoint as root and CMD as non root

Tags: docker

I want to start nginx and cron as root user and php-fpm as 1001 user. How can I do that? I thought I must create an entrypoint script where I use su-exec and start nginx and cron as root and set CMD in docker compose that starts php-fpm and also set user 1001 via docker compose.

Comment: you are using the 2 services  within the same container?

Comment: Yes...nginx and php-fpm...and Cron

Comment: I recommend you in the first place to run each service with a separate container, then you run every service with the user you want

Comment: Seems the correct path, but right now there is a posibillity to run them in the same container with different users?

Comment: yes, check  the link an my answer

Comment: Thanks, it is obviously for me now to solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to achieve that there is a bash script within Docker documentation in this link:

[multi-service_container](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/)

otherwise, I recommend you to run each service within his own container.

Answer (score 1):

the solution for this is not to use ENTRYPOINT and CMD to run each service, but to have a script which runs both services, and use that as the entrypoint.